# issues performing two-way binding in directive template with parser and formatter in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I'm having trouble figuring out how to create a two-way binding with an element inside a template for a directive in AngularJS.

My example:

## HTML

```
<div ng-app="App">
    <div ng-controller="AppCtrl">
        <input ng-model="myValue" />{{myValue}}
        <uppercase ng-model="myValue" />
    </div>    
</div>
```

## Javascript

```
var app = angular.module('App', []);

function AppCtrl($scope) {
    $scope.myValue = 'Hello World';
};

app.directive('uppercase', function() {
return {
    restrict : 'E',
    replace: true,
    require: 'ngModel',
    template: '<div><input ng-model="ngModel" /></div>', //If I remove the wrapping div, it works, but I have to change the ng-model attribute on the directive scope to be something else, such as 'model'
    scope: {
        ngModel: '=',
    },
    link: function(scope, element, attr, ngModel) {

        function parse(string) { //with the div in the template function is never called
            //alert('parsing');   
            //debugger;
            return (string || '').toLowerCase();
        }

        function format(string) { //with the div in the template, string is always 'undefined' and the function is only called once
            //alert('formatting');
            //debugger;
            return (string || '').toUpperCase();
        }
        ngModel.$parsers.push(parse);
        ngModel.$formatters.push(format);
    }
};    
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/DuHvy/7/

The problem is that the two-way binding is established, but the parser and formatter do not get called properly. The values passed to those functions is always 'undefined'.  My example will work if the element I want to bind to is the outer-most element in the template, but I need to bind to a child element.

I think I've narrowed it down to a problem with what the ngModel parameter in the link function.  I'm not very familiar with directives, so I'm not even sure what the ngModel object  is in that context.

Any help debugging this would be appreciated.

Comment: You don't need a template at all for this directive. Not even isolate scope.

Comment: Have got the same problem. Unfortunately, I can't get rid of the template (and I do need a nested input element). Did you ever solve this besides getting rid of the template?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/DuHvy/8/

This kind of directive works better as an attribute that modifies an element using an ng-model directive.   That lets you get rid of all the templating.

```
<div ng-app="App">
    <div ng-controller="AppCtrl">
        <input ng-model="myValue" />{{myValue}}
        <input uppercase ng-model="myValue" />
    </div>    
</div>
```

Comment: I tried something like that, but my original problem (which I distilled down to the given code in my question for simplicity), requires a more complex template with several elements with which I would like to replace the directive element.

Comment: I would split that directive into two: your input modifier and then use another directive to create your block of code.  Or just use a built in include directive: http://jsfiddle.net/DuHvy/9/.  The one thing to watch out for is that include creates a new scope, so I had to move your model variable inside an object for it to be writable from a child scope.

Comment: Ok. I think I get where you're coming from with splitting it up.  Your fiddle looks like it works, but if I type into the templated inputs, the plain input doesn't update and any further typing into the plain one no longer updates the ones from the template.

Comment: I was able to get it to work by splitting it up into two directives: an element directive for my complex template and an attribute directive to enhance my input with the formatter and parser.  I'm now having trouble making the other attributes on the element visible to the nested attribute directive, but that may for another question if I can't figure it out.  It appears that the {{}} expressions in the template from the element directive aren't being bound until after the nested attribute directives' link function is called.

Comment: Here's a fiddle showing my working version with the attribute problem.  In this example, the "name" attribute isn't bound until after I need it in the linking function.

http://jsfiddle.net/DuHvy/18/

Comment: I was able to solve the attribute problem by wrapping it in $observe.  It's not an elegant solution, but it works.  Thanks for your help.
http://jsfiddle.net/DuHvy/19/

Comment: Congrats!  Sorry for the broken fiddle.  I saw that problem, fixed it, but forgot to "update" before I posted the URL.  Here's the fixed version, for what it's worth: http://jsfiddle.net/DuHvy/20/